# Why does this jQuery.load example from w3schools fail to load the content every time I try to replicate it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get load content into one html file from another file. I am having trouble, and I came across [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load_callback) from w3schools. I am running it exactly as they've set it up (demo_test.txt is in the same directory as the html file I'm calling it from) and the script reports back that statusTxt = error each time, the content is not loaded.

Here's the full code...
demo_test.txt contains:

```html
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

And testjquery.html contains:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
          $("#div1").load(
            "demo_test.txt",
            function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
              if (statusTxt == "success")
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
              if (statusTxt == "error")
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
          );
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

    <button>Get External Content</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was able to get all the other jQuery examples to work, but I can't get the load function to work. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I've tried running the html file in Chrome and Firefox and they both give me the error status, and IE adds on "access denied" to the error.

Comment: Do you have `demo_test.txt` set up in the same directory as your .html page on your server?

Comment: Is there any more information about the error?  In the browser's debugging tools, does the console tell you anything?

Comment: Check the Network tab of your developer tools to see if you are successfully locating the `.txt` file.

Comment: I do have demo_test.txt in the same directory. The error I get is the error that is written into the script in if (statusTxt == "error"). It's a pop up that says "Error: 0: error". I'm going to look at the browser debugging tools but I'm not really sure how to use them.

Comment: Are you running it locally, from a webserver or where?

Comment: In the network tab of the developer tools the demo_test.txt does pop up after I click the "Get External Content" button, but the status says (pending) instead of 200 like the other files. After I click ok on the error pop up, the status says "CORS error"

Comment: I am running it locally on my computer

Comment: @boda17: "locally" as in just opening the file, or as in a local web server?  If you're opening the page from the file system then you can't make AJAX requests.  (I'm sure there's a duplicate question on this, but I haven't found it yet.)

Comment: Ok I'm looking into the CORS error. It looks like I need to enable CORS on my server? I'm running this locally for now so I think I might be able to sort that out, but I'm going to transfer these files and have them hosted on namecheap so that might be a bit more complicated. Is there a simple answer to this besides figuring out how to enable cors?

Comment: because the sample code you want to reproduce was written before the CORS rules were adopted. this example is no longer possible as it is

Comment: @david yes locally as in opening the file on my desktop. I do plan to transfer these files to my namecheap server that is hosting my website after I sort this out. I'm guessing though that sorting this issue out locally on my desktop won't fix the issue when I try to transfer it to my hosted files on namecheap

Comment: The simple answer is to have it hosted. I tested it and it works when running from a webserver.  So its just a matter of getting it hosted

Comment: @mister jojo I want to have a navigation bar on my website that is saved in a separate file and I can import to every page on my website. is there a better way to do this now? all the examples i find when i google seem to suggest this way but i guess like you said its' outdated

Comment: @boda17: *"opening the file on my desktop"* - Use a web server.  Even for development, use a localhost web server.  Opening a web page from the file system is severely limiting and doesn't match the target environment at all.

Comment: @imvain2, oh this exact code will work without me having to enable cors when i ahve it hosted by namecheap? that's awesome to hear

Comment: *"I am running it locally on my computer"* <-- **There's you're answer. You need to set up a locally running server (MS IIS, for example) or host your pages on a service.**

Comment: thank you to everyone for your answers, i'm going to try the files hosted on my website now.

Comment: If you are looking to reuse the same code for navigation, I wouldn't use this method. I would look into what server side language your host allows and use an include file in that language (most likely will be PHP).

Comment: Can confirm, the demo worked when I hosted it on my server. Not sure the protocol when the answer is solved in these comments. Do I edit my question to include the answer? Does someone type out the answer and I set it as the answer?